# Getting response from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2

Hey all i am looking to recieve a response back from the SP that i call out using VB.net. This is my code for doing just that:

```
  connection.Open()
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  command.CommandText = "RPT_C_S_H"          
  command.Parameters("@theOutput").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output  'returns 0 if bad, 1 if good
  Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
```

So now do i just do a

```
dim returnedValue as integer = 0

Do While dataReader.Read()
     returnedValue = dataReader(0)
Loop
```

in order to get the returned value?

Any help would be great! Thanks!

David

**UPDATE**

```
connection.Open()
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.CommandText = "RPT_C_S_H"
Dim sqlParReturn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@theOutput", SqlDbType.SmallInt)
sqlParReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim returnedValue As Integer = CInt(sqlParReturn.Value)
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
  Dim sqlParReturn1 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Error_Code", SqlDbType.Int)
  Dim sqlParReturn2 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Err_Msg", SqlDbType.VarChar)
  Dim sqlParReturn3 As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Bit)

  sqlParReturn1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
  sqlParReturn2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
  sqlParReturn3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

  command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Dim returnedValue1 As String = sqlParReturn1.Value
  Dim returnedValue2 As String = sqlParReturn2.Value
  Dim returnedValue3 As String = sqlParReturn3.Value
```

The SP looks like this:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSS_SP_Job_Return] (
    @job INT,
    @UserID VARCHAR(50),
    @Printer_Name VARCHAR(30),
    @Error_Code int OUTPUT,
    @Err_Msg  varchar (1000) OUTPUT,
    @result BIT OUTPUT
  )
```

I keep getting the error: **String[4] the size property has an invalid size of 0**

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more inclined to have your procedure return an INT and perform a ExecuteScalar to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this to read out the value from the SQL parameter:

```
Do While dataReader.Read()
     '' do something with your data here!
Loop

Dim value = command.Parameters("@theOutput").Value
```

But this will only work **after** you've completed reading all the rows from your data reader (assuming your stored procedure *does* indeed return some data using a `SELECT` statement - otherwise use `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of the data reader)

Comment: The return in the SP is like this **SET @theOutput = 1**

Comment: Would i put the **Dim value = command.Parameters("@theOutput").Value** AFTER **command.ExecuteNonQuery()** or BEFORE?

Comment: @StealthRT: first, you need to **execute** the stored proc - only **AFTER THAT** you can grab the output parameters....

Comment: So **command.ExecuteNonQuery()** first then right after that i do the **Dim value = command.Parameters("@theOutput").Value** correct?

Comment: OR are you saying to do **Dim value = command.Parameters("@theOutput").Value** first to save the output once **command.ExecuteNonQuery()** executes after it.

Comment: @StealthRT: **FIRST** execute the query using `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - **THEN AFTER THAT** you can read out the parameter value. The return parameters **are not defined** until after the query **has been executed**

Comment: Pleaes see my updated OP and see if that is what you are talking about :o)

Comment: @StealthRT: you're setting an **OUTPUT** parameter - that's **not** a return value! You need to use this instead: `sqlParReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`. But otherwise, the sequencing seems correct

Comment: @StealthRT: yes - and? This seems OK to me - setting up the parameters, defining them as "output", calling the stored proc, and after that, reading out the values from the stored proc - any problems with that??